# I can run Lighthouse: Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP

Tags: php

Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. Something went wrong with recording the trace over your page load. Please run Lighthouse again. (NO_FCP) .
Please help me ! Thanks U !

Comment: What were you doing to meet such an error message?

Comment: everyday i check yours website to fix images